# Login form for disconnected Architecture in c#

Tags: c#, .net, database, winforms

I am using Visual Studio 2008 to create a windows app.  I want to create a login form in a disconnected manner.  I am facing a problem that when I am trying to check the DataTable is filled or not it is showing that it is filled always.

Code for login button:

```
try
        {
            //getting connectionString
            mcc = new myConnectionClass();
            conString = mcc.MyConnection;
            //opening connection con
            con = new SqlConnection(conString);
            string queryString = "select * from LOGIN_TABLE where LOGIN_ID = @LOGIN_ID and LOGIN_PASSWORD = @LOGIN_PASSWORD";
            //dataset ds , SqlDataAdapter sda
            ds = new DataSet();
            sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            //sqlcommand 
            cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("LOGIN_ID", txtLogin.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("LOGIN_PASSWORD", txtPass.Text));
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

            sda.Fill(ds, "LOGIN_TABLE");
            //datatable dt
            dt = ds.Tables["LOGIN_TABLE"];
            //checking is datatable is empty 
            if (dt != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login Successed");
            }
            else
            {                   
                MessageBox.Show("Login Failed");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            ds.Clear();
            dt.Clear();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error lies in the check for

```
if(dt != null)
```

it's allways true if your **LOGIN_TABLE** exist

you need to check for number of rows.

```
if(dt.Rows.Count != 0)
```

Let me say also that, from a security point of view, storing login e password on a database is not a good idea.

Comment: can u tell me if something addition can be done to improve this code

Comment: Use the 'using' keyword around your SqlConnection to assure a proper close and dispose of this resource

Comment: u told storing login and password in databse is not a good idea then where to store it

Comment: Store the hash of the user's password, and not the password itself.  When a user logs in, compute the hash of his input, and compare it with the value stored in the database.  If your database ever gets compromised, only the hashed value of the password would be leaked, and not the password itself.

Comment: @Tung:  Amen!  That should be tattooed on the back of ever developer's left hand.